# How can I store the text from an input field in a variable using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-templates

I am attempting to retrieve the value of an input field, but it is returning 'None'. I am unsure of what is causing this issue and what I am missing. Can someone who is knowledgeable about this topic please review my code and provide a detailed explanation of the solution? I am a beginner in programming and would appreciate any guidance on this matter

```
<form method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}

{% bootstrap_form search_form %}

</form>

<div id="search_results"><div>

<script>
    var delayTimer;
    $('#id_search').keyup(function() {
      clearTimeout(delayTimer);
      $('#search_results').text('Loading...');
      delayTimer = setTimeout(function() {
          var text = $("#id_search").val();
          console.log(text,'search text');
          $.ajax({
            url:'{% url "videos:search_function" %}',
            data:{
                'search_term':text
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data) {
                $('#search_results').text(data['hello']);
            }
          });
      },1000);
    });
</script>
```

If more details are require than tell me iwill update my question with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is a bit incomplete.
first you have to specify that if there is any input with `id_search` id (post your final html code which browser renders)
then I'd suggest to put your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // here
})
```

Comment: here is my finall html code of search field `<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="id_search">Search</label><input type="text" name="search" maxlength="255" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" title="" id="id_search"></div>`

Comment: I guess i am using right id and everything fine ,But not storing text in a text varible

Comment: I just copied your code and it works just fine. I guess there is something wrong with the include jQuery script order. make sure you have imported jQuery script and its above your script tag. or post it here to inspect more.